# Android "Login With Facebook" callback not getting fired

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, callback

I'm integrating "Login With Facebook" into my Android app and I'm facing a weird issue that is the first time (**and only the first**) that I launch my app (just after a fresh new copy has been installed) Facebook callback is not being called after I hit the button (but does the login normally). If I login normally (or with Facebook) and then do a logout second time and onwards the callback gets fired normally.

I need the callback to do some user session operations so I'm getting mad about this, many days without being able to find a solution so I hope anyone can help me. My facebookCallBackManager() function is called in onCreate.

In my example below I need getFacebookUserData() method to get fired but setting breakpoints and debugging not even onSucces is getting fired.

Thanks in advance!

Below I paste my callback code in my ActivityLogin class:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

private void facebookCallBackManager() {

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton btnFacebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookLogin);
    btnFacebookLogin.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
    btnFacebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager,
        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error
                            } else {
                                getFacebookUserData(json);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ).executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {

                if (!GeneralUtils.isOnline(oContext)){
                    GeneralUtils.showNoInternet(strTheme, oContext, ActivityLogin.this);
                }else{
                    String strMessage=exception.getMessage();
                    GeneralUtils.showToast(strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, strTheme, ActivityLogin.this);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Edit 1:

I forgot to mention I'm using SDK 4.23.0, so SDK initialization is no longer needed.

Edit 2:

More information that might be useful.

My ActivityMain is the main and default one and when launching if user is not logged in then redirection to login is done with the next lines:

```
private void doLogin(){

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityLogin.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: When you are initializing Facebook SDK? And is your activity "SingleTask" || "SingleTop"?

Comment: Hello @Michal_196 and thanks for replying. I forgot to mention that I use SDK 4.23.0 and latest SDKs are auto-initialized so FacebookSdn.Initialize is no longer needed and regarding what kind of activity it is I'm not sure, don't know what is "SingleTask or "SingleTop" :)

Comment: I've been reading about "SingleTask" and "SingleTop" and I haven't defined none of them in my manifest file, in fact my activity declaration is as follows:

<activity
            android:name="com.testMe.login.ActivityLogin"
            android:parentActivityName="com.testMe.testMe.ActivityMain" >
</activity>

Comment: Please check my edits @Michal_196.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will answer my own question just in case it helps anyone who might be facing the same (or similar) problem, but first I have to say @Michal_196 have put me in the right direction so I first say thanks to him.

The problem of the callback not being fired the first time the app was launched has to do with the way I was calling ActivityLogin activity, in concrete: setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

My flow is to call ActivityMain and check for logged user and in case it is not I redirect to ActivityLogin and to avoid than in login after back button a user who was not logged was able to hit back and just access the app I've had added "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY" to clear main from history but I don't know why that was the culprit of callback not getting fired.

After removing that line not only callback works correctly but also if a user starts the app and is redirected to login from main and hits back button without logging app just exits as expected, weird but works!

Edit 1:

Thinking better now I understand what has happened, FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY instead of clearing main activity from stack was indicating that login activity shouldn't be put on stack and so callback was not getting fired after facebook was called, it's clear to me now and I've solved my problem. Thanks again @Michal_196.

Comment: No problem. I had also run into similar situation, and was banging my head about the same problem of callback not getting fired. In my case the culprit was "SingleTask".

Answer (score 0):

findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook_login).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

```
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginScreen.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"));
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            try {
                                String fb_id = "";
                                String email_Id = "";
                                String name = "";
                                String gender = "";
                                if (response.getJSONObject().has("id")) {
                                    fb_id = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                                }
                                email_Id = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                                gender = response.getJSONObject().getString("gender");
                                String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?type=large";   //small , large

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("TAG", "FB_LoginResponse==> Cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Exception_FB_LoginResponse==>" + exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

========================================================================
add this in your oncreate method

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

FacebookSdk.setApplicationId("here is you facebook application id");

callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your effort @Kaidjohar Mithawala. I have already resolved it the way I describe in my post above. I cannot set my own answer as resolved because it's says I have to wait for 2 days but in the end the problem was related to ACTIVITY_FLAG_NO_HISTORY when calling my login activity :)